# C# postgresql dataAdapter doubles the amount of bytes in byteArray?

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms

I have some legacy apps:

two .NET4.5 Windows apps and a PostgreSQL 9.2 database (currently running on WinXP 32bit virtual machine)

the first app saves some file into the database by this:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(CONN_STRING);
conn.Open();
pgsqlParameter cl_code = new NpgsqlParameter("@cl_code", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
NpgsqlParameter mes_text = new NpgsqlParameter("@mes_text", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
NpgsqlParameter file_name = new NpgsqlParameter("@file_name", DbType.String);
NpgsqlParameter data = new NpgsqlParameter("@data", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea);

NpgsqlCommand addComm = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into communication (createtime,channel,client_code,message,file_name,data, sent) " +
"VALUES (current_timestamp,'Email', @cl_code, @mes_text,@file_name,@data, false);", conn);

cl_code.Value = client["code"];
mes_text.Value = String.Format("Заказ {0}({1}) отправлен в производство", order["clientid"], order["id"]);
file_name.Value = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
data.Value = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

addComm.Parameters.Add(cl_code);
addComm.Parameters.Add(mes_text);
addComm.Parameters.Add(file_name);
addComm.Parameters.Add(data);

addComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

the example file has exact size of **47253** bytes:
[size of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prMGl.png)

And this is exactly what is stored into the database:

[size in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Vob.png)

The second app tries to read the file from the database like this:

```
messages.Clear();
conn.Open();

NpgsqlDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
                           
NpgsqlParameter cust = new NpgsqlParameter("@client_code", DbType.String);                                                        
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from communication WHERE channel = 'Email' AND sent = false and client_code = @client_code;", conn);

 
 cust.Value = customer["code"];
 command.Parameters.Add(cust);
 dataAdapter1.SelectCommand = command;

 messages = new DataTable();
 dataAdapter1.Fill(messages);
 conn.Close();
```

and here is the problem – the amount of bytes I read from the database is **94507**!
[debugger screen of DataRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFqFo.png)

Which looks like it was doubled: **47253 * 2 = 94506**

And the most confusing thing – there is another table with bytea column, and pretty much the same code to write and read files – and that part does`t have this issue.

Any help is much appreciated!

UPD. Found the same issue, but no solution either https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BUJrGYaKH4Nj07LMFyxDxEKK5B%2BZNuxu2p1RZH8Ft0spJ%2Bv9Q%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: The size depends on the compiler options of your app (32 or 64 bit mode) and the driver that is used in the connection string.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it has to be something with x32-64 architecture.. But there is another data table in the same database and the same apps, which also has bytea column, and there is no such problem!

Comment: PBt suppose the data is stored as 64 bit?

Comment: No, I pretty much sure it is stored as 32bit, because the database is running on 32 bit VM

Comment: So if you use 32 bit VM the 64 bit data could be in two consecutive memory locations.

Comment: Well, if I assume , that bytearray of file in 64 bit will have double size, it will mean it should also stored in the database with double size, right?


But I checked the size of the record the database , it is exactly the size of initial file

Comment: No.  The number of rows will be the same.  How did you check the size of the database?

Comment: I ran the query, that’s in my description https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Vob.png

Comment: PostgreSQL length functions that return the number of characters or the number of bytes of a string.  Is field bytes or string?  You have : ew NpgsqlParameter("@client_code", DbType.String); So a character could be two bytes which would double the size.

Comment: The parameter for this field is NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea the code to pass the value is data.Value = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath); the field has type “bytea”

Comment: Documentation says : Corresponds to the PostgreSQL "bytea" type, holding a raw byte string.  A string could be two bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution (thanks jdweng).
Postgresql has two ways to export bytearray data. To enable the right one for me I executed the following command (on database server):
'''
ALTER DATABASE your-db-name SET BYTEA_OUTPUT TO 'escape';
'''